# Stochastic Integral and Standard Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $B_t (t\geq 0)$ be a standard Brownian Motion, where $B_0=0$. I have $d(B_s^2)= 2B_sdB_s$. I want to find the integral $ \int_0^tB_sdB_s$. Therefore, I get $ \int_0^tB_sdB_s= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^td(B_s^2)$. May I know how should I proceed? Is it possible to relate this to the mean of $B_t^2$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(B_t^2)$?

Comment: Indeed, you get $\int_{0}^{T} \mathrm{d}(B_s^2) = B_T^2 - B_0^2$.

Comment: The answer is actually $\frac{B_t^2-t}{2}$ and I know $\mathbb{E}(B_t^2)=t$, so I am trying to relate these two parts.

Comment: The reason is that $\mathrm{d}(B_t^2) \neq 2B_t \, \mathrm{d}B_t$. This is not the ordinary Stieltjes integral, and in fact, Ito's Formula tell that $$\mathrm{d}(B_t^2) = 2B_t \, \mathrm{d}B_t + \mathrm{d}t.$$ The rationale behind this is that, if we write $f(x)=x^2$, then $$\mathrm{d}f(B_t)=f(B_t + \mathrm{d}B_t)-f(B_t) = f'(B_t)\,\mathrm{d}B_t+\frac{1}{2}f''(B_t)(\mathrm{d}B_t)^2 + \cdots, $$ and the infinitesimal quadratic variation term $(\mathrm{d}B_t)^2$ also contributes to the integral! (Its contribution would look like $(\mathrm{d}B_t)^2=\mathbb{E}[(\mathrm{d}B_t)^2]=\mathrm{d}t$.)

Comment: May I know how did you get the last equation $(dB_t)^2 =dt$?

Comment: The relation $(\mathrm{d}B_t)^2=\mathrm{d}t$ is only a heuristic reflection a more prigorous fact that the quadratic variation of $(B_t)$ on $[a, b]$ is $b-a$: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} (B_{t_i}-B_{t_{i-1}})^2 \xrightarrow[\text{in probability}]{\|\Pi\| \to 0} b - a, $$ where the limit is taken along the partitions $\Pi = \{a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=b\}$ of $[a, b]$. However I would be surprised if the Ito's formula doesn't appear on any of the textbooks or notes you are consulting.